# How to use --force-with-lease with (GitPython) git.remote.Remote?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to be Pythonic. Thus, I have this code:

```py
import git
import uuid

repo = git.Repo(...)
u = repo.create_remote(uuid.uuid4(), 'https://github.com/...')
```

If I *wasn't* trying to be pythonic, I could do this:

```py
repo.git.push(u.name, refspec, '--force-with-lease')
```

...but I *am* trying to be Pythonic. How do I do a `--force-with-lease` push using this (`git.remote.Remote`) object?

```py
u.push(refspec, help=needed)
```

It looks like I can say:

```py
u.push(refspec, force=True)
```

...but I don't think that uses a lease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a quick look at the source code of GitPython, I would guess that it turns `_` into `-` when interpreting the `**kwargs`. I think the correct way should be:

```
u.push(refspec, force_with_lease=True)
```

---

Based on: [function `dashify()`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/52ee6c19423297b4c667d34ed1bd621dafaabb0e/git/cmd.py#L127), which is called from [function `transform_kwarg()`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/52ee6c19423297b4c667d34ed1bd621dafaabb0e/git/cmd.py#L890).